# How to find inner dimensions of polygon(s) in C#

Tags: unity-game-engine, vector, line, polygon, vector-graphics

The user is allowed to draw the lines that are created from the points to create different rooms.

As they're rooms, I'd like to show only the inner dimensions of created room/ Polygon.

What is the best way to detect the inner region of the area that may be created by a set of intersections/ Points given that the line/ wall has thickness?

Implementation will be done in Unity 3D

[image: Please find the attached image here]

Comment: Apply the polygon area formula and substract the half of the lines area. Wouldn't that approximation work?

Comment: Is this a homework request? It looks a bit like one ... Since you know your points you know exactly in which direction the line goes -> at the overlapping points you know that you have to move (lineThinkess * 0.5f * directionPerpendicularToLine) for both lines that is your actual corner point. This returns 4 possible points -> assuming that as you show the rooms are convex -> chose the one point that is closest to the center of the overlapping positions